# Unable to get navigator.notification.alert("test") working on a Phonegap android app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I was following the tutorial to make an android app using phonegap (http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/phonegap/phonegap-from-scratch/). The app is supposed to display a popup alert using javascript but this isn't working. Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong? Here's my code for the HTML file (index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
<title>mobiletuts phonegap</title>
  <script src="phonegap-1.2.0.js"></script>
  <script>
     function onLoad(){
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
     }
     function onDeviceReady(){
      navigator.notification.alert("PhoneGap is working!!");
     }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="onLoad();">
       <h1>Welcome to PhoneGap</h1>
       <h2>Edit assets/www/index.html</h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's the code for the main java file in the src folder:

```
package com.my.namespace;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.phonegap.DroidGap;

public class HelloPhonegapActivity extends DroidGap {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

I did set the permissions in the android manifest file exactly as specified on http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/phonegap/phonegap-from-scratch/.

Thanks!

Comment: Additional details: I tried running it on a 2.3 emulator, Galaxy S running 2.3, and finally on an ICS running emulator and it did not work on any of them.

Comment: and you see the `h1` and `h2`, but you don't see the alert? or in which way it isnt working?

Answer (score 0):

I just realized I had a different version of phonegap.js in my source folder than the one I was referring to in the html script tag. It works now!